# How to add onClick to LayersControl's checkbox and string label?

Tags: react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I'm using [React Leaflet's components](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-layers-control/) to compose a list of dynamically added data layers as follows, which nicely adds that layer to the `LayersControl` that's wrapping it all.

```
<LayersControl.Overlay checked name={layer.name}>
    <GeoJSON
        data={layer.data}
        onEachFeature={(feature, localLayer) => {
           localLayer.on({
               click: event => onFeatureSelect(event, feature),
            })
        }}
        style={getStyle}
        type={layer.type}
    />
</LayersControl.Overlay>
```

I now would like to add additional functionality for every layer, like filtering based on user input (e.g. only show features that match this and that). Therefore I am looking for a way to bind an `onClick` to the list of layers in the `LayersControl`. An alternative would be to fully customize the `LayersControl`, something that seems to be way too verbose for my need. `onClick` doesn't work, nor can I get a list of all my overlays programmatically to do what I want.

If I drop the React Leaflet way of doing it, meaning creating those layers programmatically, it seems rather simple. But I appreciate the simplicity and readability of code produced with that library and would like to find a way. Can anybody point me at a solution, any feedback is appreciated.

P.S. HNY!!!